# what is the problem in my predict function?

Tags: keras

i am working on  a binary video classification problem i convert every video to 7 images and extract features from those images with vgg16 and then feed the sequence of images to my LSTM

LSTM work with sequence this mean that every 7 images is a single sequence with a single label so after i extracted my features i had to create my labels(one label for one sequence of 7 images) and then feed the LSTM with my data

i used (keras.utils.to_categorical) to incode the labels i created before i feed the LSTM with it using one for the first class and zero for the second class but when i try to predict after small training it give me results with different numbers that is not zero or one although it must give me zero or one as i feed it with those numbers

i  dont care with my accuracy or the loss percentage i just want to know why i get different value of classes

this is my code from the LSTM and label creating process  :

here i create 2 arrays one have 45 one (first class) and 45 zero (second class) for 108 sequence for training and the other array have 11 one (first class) and 11 zero (second class) for validattion and i use (keras.utils.to_categorical)

```
t_labels = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
v_labels = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
t_labels= keras.utils.to_categorical(t_labels, num_classes=2)
v_labels= keras.utils.to_categorical(v_labels, num_classes=2)
```

here is my LSTM :

```
lstm1 = Sequential()
lstm1.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(7,25088)))
lstm1.add(LSTM(60, activation='relu'))
lstm1.add(Dropout(0.6))
lstm1.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
lstm1.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
lstm1.add(Dense(2 , activation='softmax'))

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
adam = Adam(lr=2e-5,beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999)

lstm1.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

lstm1.fit(lstm_train_sample , t_labels , epochs=30 , batch_size=9 , validation_data=(lstm_validation_sample,v_labels) , validation_batch_size= 2 )

features_batch = lstm1.predict(lstm_validation_sample,batch_size=1)
features_batch
array([[7.10002226e-08, 9.99999881e-01],
       [1.12060457e-06, 9.99998927e-01],
       [5.34564265e-07, 9.99999523e-01],
       [6.33320667e-07, 9.99999404e-01],
       [3.10866085e-06, 9.99996901e-01],
```

so if i try to print my labels it looks like this :

```
 [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
```

but when i try to predict results looks like i showed above:

```
array([[7.10002226e-08, 9.99999881e-01],
       [1.12060457e-06, 9.99998927e-01],
       [5.34564265e-07, 9.99999523e-01],
       [6.33320667e-07, 9.99999404e-01],
       [3.10866085e-06, 9.99996901e-01],
```

i dont care now even the loss was 100 precent it should just show me wrong answers with the lables i used not with this strange numbers

so i need some help here please if someone know whats the problem or what mistake i did in my code

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the code, just your wrong interpretation of what predict outputs, see the duplicate answer on how to get class indices

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two classes in your target feature, I would suggest you to use 'Sigmoid' activation function instead of 'Softmax' in the last layer of your model . Softmax activation is largely used for multiclass classification.

Change this line of code :

```
lstm1.add(Dense(2 , activation='softmax'))
```

To :

```
lstm1.add(Dense(2 , activation='sigmoid'))
```

See if that helps.